# Ошибка при выполнении sql-запроса. Java. JDBC

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, playframework

В БД есть таблица user, изначально пустая, создается методом createTable()

```
public void createTable() throws SQLException {
    connect = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, LOGIN, PASSWORD);
    Statement statement = connect.createStatement();
    statement.execute("create table user(" +
    "login varchar(100) primary key, " +
    "password varchar(100));");
    statement.close();
    connect.close();
}
```

Имеется метод registrateUser()

```
public void registrateUser() throws SQLException {
    String login = "login";
    String password = "password";
    addUser(login, password);
}
```

из этого метода вызывается метод addUser(String login, String password), который добавляет запись в БД

```
public void addUser(String login, String password) throws SQLException 
{
    connect = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, LOGIN, PASSWORD);
    PreparedStatement statement = connect
            .prepareStatement("insert into user(login, password) values(?, ?)");
    statement.setString(1, login);
    statement.setString(2, password);
    statement.executeUpdate();
}
```

При компиляции вылетает ошибка:

> CompletionException: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: NULL not allowed
>   for column "LOGIN"; SQL statement: insert into user(login, password)
>   values(?, ?)

Не могу понять откуда там NULL берется и почему не работает?

**UPDATE** Имена немного поменялись в процессе, но на суть проблемы не повлияло:

```
public class UserDB {
    public static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:h2:~/test";
    public static final String LOGIN = "sa";
    public static final String PASSWORD = "";
    private static Connection connect = null;

    public void initUserDB() throws SQLException {
        connect = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, LOGIN, PASSWORD);
        Statement statement = connect.createStatement();
        statement.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user(login varchar(20) primary key, password varchar(20));");
    }

    public void addUser(String login, String password) throws SQLException 
    {
        connect = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, LOGIN, PASSWORD);
        PreparedStatement statement = connect
                .prepareStatement("insert into user(login, password) values(?, ?)");
        statement.setString(1, login);
        statement.setString(2, password);
        statement.executeUpdate();
    }

    public class HomeController extends Controller {
        private static UserDB registeredUsers = new UserDB();

        public Result registrateUser() throws SQLException {
            String login = request().getQueryString("login");
            String password = request().getQueryString("password");
            registeredUsers.addUser(login, password);
            return  ok("Successful registration");
        }

        public void dbInit() throws SQLException {
            registeredUsers.initUserDB();
        }
    }
}
```

Вот такой стектрейс по этой ошибке выдает фреймворк:

```
play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$$anon$1: Execution      exception[[CompletionException: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: NULL not allowed for column "LOGIN"; SQL statement:
insert into user(login, password) values(?, ?) [23502-192]]]
at play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$.throwableToUsefulException(HttpErrorHandler.scala:293)
at play.api.http.DefaultHttpErrorHandler.onServerError(HttpErrorHandler.scala:220)
at play.api.GlobalSettings$class.onError(GlobalSettings.scala:160)
at play.api.DefaultGlobal$.onError(GlobalSettings.scala:188)
at play.api.http.GlobalSettingsHttpErrorHandler.onServerError(HttpErrorHandler.scala:100)
at play.core.server.netty.PlayRequestHandler$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(PlayRequestHandler.scala:100)
at play.core.server.netty.PlayRequestHandler$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(PlayRequestHandler.scala:99)
at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$recoverWith$1.apply(Future.scala:344)
at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$recoverWith$1.apply(Future.scala:343)
at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: NULL not allowed for column "LOGIN"; SQL statement:
insert into user(login, password) values(?, ?) [23502-192]
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:292)
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:308)
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniApply(CompletableFuture.java:593)
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniApply.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:577)
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:474)
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:1977)
at scala.concurrent.java8.FuturesConvertersImpl$CF.apply(FutureConvertersImpl.scala:21)
at scala.concurrent.java8.FuturesConvertersImpl$CF.apply(FutureConvertersImpl.scala:18)
at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32)
at scala.concurrent.BatchingExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.processBatch$1(BatchingExecutor.scala:63)
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: NULL not allowed for column "LOGIN"; SQL statement:
insert into user(login, password) values(?, ?) [23502-192]
at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345)
at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:179)
at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:155)
at org.h2.table.Column.validateConvertUpdateSequence(Column.java:311)
at org.h2.table.Table.validateConvertUpdateSequence(Table.java:784)
at org.h2.command.dml.Insert.insertRows(Insert.java:151)
at org.h2.command.dml.Insert.update(Insert.java:114)
at org.h2.command.CommandContainer.update(CommandContainer.java:98)
at org.h2.command.Command.executeUpdate(Command.java:258)
at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:160)
```

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос структуру таблицы.

Comment: А дебаг что говорит, переменные действительно null?

Comment: Добавил в вопрос метод, который создает таблицу пустую. Дебаг показывает что в переменных метода значение, которые туда и передавались.

Comment: Прошу прощения, за опубликованный неверный ответ - невнимательно прочитал Ваш код.

Comment: @kernel40, я возможно Вас удивлю, но Ваш код работает. Во всяком случае, то что Вы нам предоставили добавляет пользователя с логином login и паролем password. Могу предположить что если ошибка и есть где, то в продолжении метода `registrateUser`. Вы можете предоставить больше данных для анализа?

Comment: @kernel40 , https://i.stack.imgur.com/iSElU.png , результаты добавления видны в правом окне. Единственное, что я отредактировал там - убрал повтороное получение соединения в методе addUser - но это было непроизвольно. Всё отработало нормально.

Comment: @kernel40 , приведите полный код класса или хотя бы метода registrateUser

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Привожу классы с кодом в вопрос.

Comment: Логика такая: в классе HomeController я получаю логин и пароль в виде обычных String и помещаю в БД, все отрабатывает нормально до строки PreparedStatement statement = connect
            .prepareStatement("insert into user(login, password) values(?, ?)"); Тут возникает вышеописанная ошибка. Есть еще момент: все это делается в playframework, но как мне кажется это простейшая операция и дело совсем не в нем

Comment: @kernel40, не могли бы ещё полностью или частично привести stacktrace?

Comment: Добавил стектрейс в вопрос, который выдает фреймворк

Comment: @kernel40, как же долго scala компилируется %)

Comment: это Вы точно подметили =)

Comment: Сначала, я также разделил код на два класса (но без использования Play) и проверил. Мне важна была принципиально работа с БД и Ваш код работал и успешно добавлял пользователя. Как мне не хотелось но пришлось развернуть приложение на Play...но меня ждало "Unexpected exception: The compilation failed without reporting any problem!"..что меня крайне позабавило. Поэтому если я и воспроизведу целиком и полностью Вашу проблему, то это будет не скоро...сообщение об ошибке мне не внушает надежды и доверия. В остальном же всё работает...Единственное - у меня был mysql коннектор...может быть в этом дело

Comment: Спасибо, что заинтересовались. Буду благодарен за ответ